# How convert Word file page to png image using C#, if document A3 format and landscape orientation?

Tags: c, image, ms-word

I used this code. It works well, but only when word document A4 format. When the format A3 and landscape orientation, the image is cropped right side by ~15%.

P.S. If format A3 and portrait orientation, the image is cropped down side by ~15%.

```
var docPath = Path.Combine(startupPath, filename1);
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

MessageFilter.Register();

app.Visible = true;

var doc = app.Documents.Open(docPath);

doc.ShowGrammaticalErrors = false;
doc.ShowRevisions = false;
doc.ShowSpellingErrors = false;

if (!Directory.Exists(startupPath + "\\" + filename1.Split('.')[0]))
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(startupPath + "\\" + filename1.Split('.')[0]);
}

//Opens the word document and fetch each page and converts to image
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Window window in doc.Windows)
{
      foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Pane pane in window.Panes)
      {
            for (var i = 1; i <= pane.Pages.Count; i++)
            {
                 var page = pane.Pages[i];
                 var bits = page.EnhMetaFileBits;
                 var target = Path.Combine(startupPath + "\\" + filename1.Split('.')[0], string.Format("{1}_page_{0}", i, filename1.Split('.')[0]));

                 try
                 {
                     using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])(bits)))
                     {
                          var image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                          var pngTarget = Path.ChangeExtension(target, "png");
                          image.Save(pngTarget, ImageFormat.Png);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (System.Exception ex)
                 { }
         }
    }
}
doc.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
app.Quit(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
MessageFilter.Revoke();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem in the Word 2007. Reinstalled to office 2010